# StringBuilder in Java

Tags: java, stringbuilder

Quick question:

```
public class AppendStringBuilder {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        sb1.append("java");
        sb1.append(new Person("Oracle"));
        System.out.println(sb1);
    }
}

package hello;
public class Person {

    String name;
    Person(String str){
        name = str;
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:
javahello.Person@2c538cc2

Reason behind this? Does not print JavaOracle

Comment: Why would it print `JavaOracle`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to implement `toString` in class `Person`:

```
public class Person {

    String name;
    Person(String str){
        name = str;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return name;
    }

}
```

`toString` must return a String representation of the object. Utility methods such as `append` invoke `toString` on an object to retrieve its textual representation.

From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29):

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
>   toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this
>   object. The result should be a concise but informative representation
>   that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all
>   subclasses override this method.
>
> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of
>   the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
>   character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
>   code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal
>   to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Add a toString method to the Person class.

```
package hello;
public class Person {

    String name;
    Person(String str){
        name = str;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sb1.append(new Person("Oracle"));`

results into

`sb1.append(new Person("Oracle").toString());`

Since your `Person` class does not override `toString()` method from `Object` class, it uses the default implementation which is to print `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`.

To print `javaOracle`, you need to override the `toString()` method as

```
public class Person {

    String name;
    Person(String str){
        name = str;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```